# Using Wok for first time?

Tags: wok

I've been given a wok recently in preparation for university, and wanted to practice cooking with it before I left, and read in the instructions that I had to season it first.

I started by washing the wok in hot soapy water for a few minutes with a dishcloth. I then tried it with kitchen towel and heated it to high on the electric hob ( I've read it's prefered to use a gas hob but I don't have one ). It made the room smell like metal for a few minutes - does this mean I have not cleaned it well enough?

I then washed it again before heating it on max. When it had gotten hot enough ( water drops evaporated after a couple of seconds), I added a tablespoon of vegetable oil to the wok. The room smelled like vegetable oil instead. I spread the oil around the pan, and then let it smoke until most of the pan had turned black/brown.

Have I done this correctly, and will their be factory oil in the patina? Should I start again or is this pan ok to use?

[image]

Comment: Yes, can I salvage the wok by giving it a serious scrub and then using an oven seasoning method instead? Will there still be factory oil present?

Comment: There should not be any factory oil after you washed the wok

Comment: Ok, I thought that I had failed to clean it correctly due to the metal smell when heated - forgot to use a scouring pad, so I wasn't sure if I'd removed all of the coating.

Comment: remember that the more you use the wok, the better it'll get.